# Linux command line - grabbing parts of the file path

Tags: linux, audio, terminal

I'm in the process of attempting to convert all my WAV files to FLAC files in such a way that my music directory for FLACs is identical to my music directory for WAVs.

At the moment I have my music archive set up, such that a typical album is here:

/directory1/directory2/directory3/Music/**WAV**/Artist/Album

So I would like a one-to-one correspondance for my FLAC files that looks as follows:

/directory1/directory2/directory3/Music/**FLAC**/Artist/Album.

I know that I will have to use `find` to list all the directories/subdirectories as follows:

`find -type d -exec commands.sh`

But how do I write the `commands.sh` file such that it will grab the `Artist/Album` part of the path in the WAV directory, `mkdir` the same /Artist/Album in the FLAC directory, and then output the flacs to the FLAC/Artist/Album directory?

I know the command for converting flacs to an output directory of your choice is:

`flac -5 --out-prefix="/desired/output/path" *.wav`

So I guess I'm just having trouble with grabbing/recreating the file paths!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a whole lot easier in a scripting language like ruby, perl or python. Something like this is a fairly straightforward starter project in any of those languages. There are libraries for find and path manipulation that make this
all pretty easy.

However, there are two posix utilities that can help with splitting apart pathnames. dirname and basename. I think those two and sed should let you do
what you want.

Find will always return relative paths and any exec occurs in the directory of the target by default, if this is not what you want look in the man pages. You can force find to stay in the top level directory.